# Query con campos de diferentes tablas

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy montando un **CRUD** y quiero juntar campos de diferentes tablas, esto serían:

- Tabla clientes: idcliente, nombre y apellido
- Tabla factura: idfactura y cantidad

El código que del *SELECT* sería:

```
$id  = $_GET[ "IdCliente" ];
$nom = $_GET[ "Nombre" ];
$ape = $_GET[ "Apellido" ];
$idfactura = $_GET[ "IdFactura" ];



$consulta = "SELECT Idcliente, nombre, apellido, idfactura.factura 
    WHERE Idcliente=:idcli, Nombre=:nomcli, Apellido=:apecli, Idfactura=:idfact"
```

¿Está bien redactado este código?

Comment: Te has dejado código por añadir a la pregunta?

Comment: @Galbi si es todo el codigo, obviamente que en otra pagina llamada index habrian definidos algunos inputs del formulario y dentro estarian los name, lo que puse en variables al principio.Pero tomando eso en consideracion,¿estaría bien?

Comment: Para saber si estas montando bien tus consultas puedes probarlas en una herramienta como *phpMyAdmin*

Comment: @Orici Yo estoy usando dreamweaver con el paquete wamp y reservo phpmyadmin para otras cosas, directamente quiero porbarlo en el dreamweaver

Comment: No, de hecho eso no pasaría por el interprete de PHP. Un crud, según la wiki (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRUD) es un conjunto de operaciones sobre una tabla, en concreto creado, borrado, actualización y lectura. Según veo en tu pregunta, hay 2 tablas, así que necesitarías un crud sobre cada uno de ellas. El código que tienes es un select  que sería la de lectura. Te faltaría "delete", "insert" y "update". Y esto sobre cada una de las dos tablas con las que quieres trabajar. Y si tu pregunta es si la consulta está bien me temo que tampoco, falta el from.

Comment: @Galbi si gracias, es solo un ejemplo com señect , despues me faltan los demas y si pongo, from cliente,¿me tiraria error no?

Comment: Si si, lo de las asignaciones está bien. Esa parte perfecta. El problema es el resto. Mira, mirate alguna pagina que te enseñe cómo hacer un crud, algún tutorial sencillito aunq sea, porque parece q vas un poco perdido. http://anexsoft.com/p/57/realizando-un-crud-listar-registrar-actualizar-eliminar-con-php   Una vez tengas lo del tutorial claro creo q no tendrás muchos más problemas.

Comment: @Galbi creo que ha dicho que estaba empezando con el SELECT. Y como dices, esta incorrecto, falta la parte del FROM en la consulta.

Comment: @Galbi hice un curso php en linea pero en ninguna parte mostraban esa propiedad, seria lo unico que me inquieta, ya que el resto esta bien seteado y por no saber esto me sucede que tuve que poner campos de oa misma tabla

Comment: @Orici si pongo en el from:FROM cliente ¿no tiraria error en la parte de la llamada al campo de otra tabla?

Comment: Si en entre los campos referencias a una tabla que no pones en el from te dará un error. Si la tabla cliente está ligada con la de factura por el campo idCliente en el from debería poner algo como: from cliente join factura on cliente id = factura.idCliente. Una vez hecho esto faltaría hacer el prepare sobre la consulta para sustituir los atributos marcados por :nombre por los valores reales.

Comment: @Galbi ¿y si no es un campo relacionado?¿podria poner cualquier campo de la tabla factura en este query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, el campo *Idcliente* debería ser una clave primaría o en todo caso un campo de tipo único. Es el único dato que vas a necesitar para consultar datos de la tabla *clientes*. Supongo que en la tabla *factura* tienes un FK que te la va a relacionar con la de *clientes*.

Prueba la consulta:

```
$consulta = "SELECT 
    clientes.Idcliente, 
    clientes.nombre, 
    clientes.apellido, 
    factura.idfactura
        FROM clientes, factura
        WHERE clientes.Idcliente=:idcli 
            AND factura.Idcliente=:idcli";
```

Te recomiendo que te crees una base de datos sencilla con algunos registros, y pruebes a hacer consultas y otras operaciones antes de tratar de integrarlas en una aplicación.

Comment: Perfecto eso necesitaba, en realidad lo que sucede es que hay 3 tablas y la tercera tiene idcliente y idfactura que relaciona a las otras dos

Comment: Entonces ¿cambia en algo esa tercer tabla que se llama cliente_factura ?

Comment: @Santi Corso ¿existe esa tercera tabla? No debería... Un buen diseño de la base de datos es la base de todo. Sino vas a tener problemas en cascada.